# No query results for model at boot created event

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model with `boot` function which has `created` event like below.

However, I sometimes (not all the time) get `No query results for model` on `ProcessAddressRefine` which is a job. As far as I understand, `created` event should happen after record is created, so there is no way that there is no query result unless it gets deleted right after it has been created. I also wonder that looking at the DB record, `ProcessAddressRefine` job is properly executed.

What would be the problem in this case?

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Model**

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::created(function ($model) {
        if (!$model->lat || !$model->lng) {
            ProcessAddressRefine::dispatch($model);
        }
    });
}
```

**Job**

```
class ProcessAddressRefine implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    private $place;

    public function __construct($place)
    {
        $this->place = $place;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->place->addressRefine()) {
            $this->place->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Extra**

```
public function addressRefine()
{
    $helper = new MapHelper();
    $coordinate = $helper->addressToCoordinate($geo_code_address);
    if ($coordinate !== false) {
        $this->lat = $coordinate['lat'];
        $this->lng = $coordinate['lng'];
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show part of the `ProcessAddressRefine` where you get the error mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming job is queued it's quite possible that model is created, then you dispatch the job, then model is deleted and then job is really executed and you are getting this message because model doesn't exist any more.

Comment: there is no deletion logic and like i mentioned above the record is totally fine.

Comment: @smchae And what happens inside of `$coordinate = $helper->addressToCoordinate($geo_code_address);`? It's also not included

Answer (score 0):

This was because of `DB::transaction` when Order record is created.